# How can I expand ext4 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, lubuntu, 16.10, reinstall

I have tried a couple of ways to expand my root partition on a dual boot (Lubuntu-Win7) machine but have not succeeded yet. I am thinking about reinstalling Lubuntu, would it be possible adding some unallocated volume to the ext4 partition during that process?

[image: screenshot of GParted]

Comment: What is your current partition layout, do you use lvm, how are you trying to expand your root partition?

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: Screenshot has been added.

Comment: You do not need to reinstall the System. But to expand your root partition, you have to boot into a live system (sort of "Try Ubuntu"). From there, start gparted, move the swap partition (dev/sda6) to the beginning of the unallocated space, and then extend the lubuntu root partition (/dev/sda7) to the left. This will take some time, as the blocks have to be copied. After that, you should be able to reboot to lubuntu.